# Did JQuery put everything into one reference?

Tags: jquery

For the old version of JQuery is this all included in the newer 1.12.2/jquery.min.js?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form-2.47.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.1.dialog.min.js"></script>
```

For example would this below do everything the above JQuery calls for (just a newer version)?

```
<script src="1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery UI and jquery are separate. here is the changelog for that version of jQuery.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/compare/1.12.1...1.12.2

So no, they didn't put everything into one reference. That would be a terribly idea due to the additional overhead of everyone not needing jQuery UI.

You will need to build a custom version of jquery UI that has the features you require, and add it in as a reference alongside jQuery itself.

https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: What about the jquery.form-2.47.js?  Is that part of the UI?

Comment: At a guess, it looks like a plugin written by a 3rd party abstract to the core libraries. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: As such, you'll need to reference it too.